# Delay an Adobe call created in Event bases rule, triggering as (s.t) through AA section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am facing an issue with Variables with "Evar and Prop"

When I am  browsing this link: http://www.te.com/global-en/search.html?q=test . Select the DTM switch and refresh the page.  Then apply a filter (i.e. select Aerospace from Industries dropdown).  Now open the developer's console and type `s.eVar55`.  You should get the output as `''`.

Now type `_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test");`  in the console.  You should now see the output which is expected as per the filter applied by the user.

The `_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test");` data element has been mapped to `eVar55/prop55`, but the first time the filter is applied, `eVar55/prop55` will show the value as `''`.

Subsequent filters applied take the previous value of the data element
every time the data element is populated with a correct value, but `eVar55` always shows the previous value from all subsequently applied filters and not showing a value when the first filter is applied.

**"Code which I have written in the Adobe DTM custom editor"**

```
if(_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test") && _satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test") !== null){
  s.linkTrackVars='eVar55,prop55';
  s.eVar55=_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test");
  s.prop55=_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test");
}
```

- Please note that whenever filter click applied output of filter text -

My problem is the timing of AJAX responses displayed with the text of the selected filter.  The Adobe Image Request is fired off way before the AJAX response, so `s.eVar55/s.prop55` is not populated with a value after the first filter is applied.

However the second and all subsequent filters are populated with the previous filter text value.

How can I delay the Adobe call which has been created in Event bases rule and triggering as `(s.t)` through adobe analytics section?

Comment: Hi @crayon, can you help me to provide the answer of this ?

Comment: It looks as if you were able to resolve your issue. You should answer the question and select it as the answer for others who encounter the same issue.